# DirectX 12 shader with improper input layout is working

Tags: c++, directx, directx-12

I made a test shader that draw green meshes on screen.
I execute the shader with vertices that have a different layout from what specified in the pipeline state and the vertex shader. Everything works, but why?

**My CPU vertices** that i upload to the GPU, then feed them to ID3D12GraphicsCommandList::IASetVertexBuffers(...):

```
struct Vertex
{
    Math::Vec3 position;
    Math::Vec3 normal;
    Math::Vec3 tangent;
    Math::Vec3 bitangent;
    Math::Vec2 texCoord;
};
using VertexArray = std::vector<Vertex>;
```

**The vertex shader:**

```
struct VS_INPUT
{
    float3 position : POSITION;
};

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 position: SV_POSITION;
};

cbuffer VertexShaderCB : register(b0)
{
    float4x4 viewProjMatrix;
};

VS_OUTPUT main(VS_INPUT input)
{
    VS_OUTPUT output;
    output.position = mul(float4(input.position, 1.0f), viewProjMatrix);

    return output;
}
```

**The pixel shader:**

```
struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 position: SV_POSITION;
};

float4 main(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    return float4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

**The shader pipeline state input layout**:

```
D3D12_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inputLayoutElement[] =
{
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
};
```

As you can see both the vertex shader and the pipeline state specify a single float3 as vertex layout.
But my vertex buffers contain positions, normals, tangents, bitangents and tex coords.
**How is the shader still working**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are allowed to ignore additional vertex components (the proper stride value will skip all the extra data). The only requirement is that vertex shader must match up with the input layout.

You are NOT allowed to have "holes" or to rearrange vertex components in Direct3D 10, 11, or 12.

```
// This is not allowed with your structure
struct VS_INPUT
{
    float3 position : POSITION;
    Math::Vec2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0;
};

// This won't work either
struct VS_INPUT
{
    Math::Vec2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 position : POSITION;
};
```

The same rules apply when binding between the vertex and pixel shader stages.

See [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/direct3d10/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-d3d9-to-d3d10-considerations#shader-signatures-and-linkage)

> It's not memory efficient in terms of GPU cache usage, but it does work.

Comment: Marvelous. Thank you very much :)